# How do you identify the difference between files in 2 different directories (including the subdirectories within the 2 dirs) to then create a patch?

Tags: python, visual-studio, command-line, diff, virtual-environment

I am looking to create a patch for my project so I may 'automatically' implement changes to specific packages (i.e. `pycaret`, `sklearn`, etc.) as I continue to develop my project in the future.

I have installed these packages on a virtual environment (`venv_A`) and edited their code to better suit my project needs.

On a second virtual environment (`venv_B`), I have installed the same packages *without* the changes.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

- venv_A: virtual environment with changes to packages' manually implemented
- venv_B: virtual environment with packages unchanged

I imagine I must do a diff command in via the terminal, and have tried the following syntax to ignore pycache (.pyc) files:

```
diff -x -ruN '*.pyc' -r venv_B venv_A
```

Rather than identifying the correct files to which I changed manually and for which I intend to create a patch, the result showed unexpected changes, many of which came from the seemingly useless text file "RECORD", the path of which was "venv_B/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wordcloud-1.8.2.2.dist-info/RECORD" (identified unintentional changes to the wordcloud package).

I have gone back into each virtual environment and confirmed that, for each file which I intend to include in the patch, the change is reflected in venv_A and not in venv_B.

Is there a good way I can resolve this issue, so that I can identify - and therefore, create an effective patch for - the differences between the code (packages) in venv_A (changed) and venv_B (original)?